# Prestashop 1.7.6.5 : sorting product by characteristics

Tags: php, prestashop-1.7

I want to be able to display my products by sorting them by characteristics (ps_feature).
How to do and which files to modify?
I managed to do this sort by modifying the templates/catalog/_partial/products.tpl file and creating a function in the override/classes/Product.php file and it works.
But it works if I display all my products without pagination. As soon as I set up a pagination (50 products per page for example), the function only works for each group of 50 products but not for all the products!
I must have to make this modification in another file before but I do not know which one (categoryController.php, ...)?
Thanks for your help

**I modify this file : products.tpl with the new function getOrdreFeatureProduct:**

```
<div class="products row">
{$tabFeatureProduct = Product::getOrdreFeatureProduct($listing.products)}

{** {foreach from=$listing.products item="product"} **}
{foreach from=$tabFeatureProduct item="product"}
    {$display = Product::getProductsWithRights($product.id, $category.id, $customer.id)}
    {if $display == "true"}
        {block name='product_miniature'}
            {include file='catalog/_partials/miniatures/product.tpl' product=$product}
        {/block}
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```

**And here is my function which allows to re-sort the characteristics :**

```
public static function getOrdreFeatureProduct($tabprod)
{   // Nouveau Tri :
    //      - Famille       -> ['features'][x]['name'] == 'Famille'
    //      - Lieux         -> ['features'][x]['name'] == 'Lieux'
    //      - Type          -> ['features'][x]['name'] == 'Type'
    //      - Collecion     -> ['features'][x]['name'] == 'Collection'  
    //      - Ss-Catégorie  -> ['features'][x]['name'] == 'Sous-Categorie'  
    
    //***** 1er TRI sur la Famille *****
    foreach($tabprod as $key => $value) 
    {   //recherche de la clé Famille
        $clef='';
        foreach($value['features'] as $kf => $vf)
        {   if($vf['name'] == 'Famille')
            {   $clef = $kf;
            }
        }
        
        $tri_famille[$key] = $value['features'][$clef]['value'];
    }
    
    //***** 2ème TRI sur le LIEUX_PDF *****
    foreach($tabprod as $key => $value) 
    {   //recherche de la clé Lieux
        $clef='';
        foreach($value['features'] as $kf => $vf)
        {   if($vf['name'] == 'Lieux_PDF')
            {   $clef = $kf;
            }
        }
        
        $tri_lieux[$key] = $value['features'][$clef]['value'];
    }
    
    //***** 3ème TRI sur le TYPE *****
    foreach($tabprod as $key => $value) 
    {   //recherche de la clé Type
        $clef='';
        foreach($value['features'] as $kf => $vf)
        {   if($vf['name'] == 'Type')
            {   $clef = $kf;
            }
        }
        
        $tri_type[$key] = $value['features'][$clef]['value'];
    }
    
    //***** 4ème TRI sur la Collection PDF *****
    foreach($tabprod as $key => $value) 
    {   //recherche de la clé Type
        $clef='';
        foreach($value['features'] as $kf => $vf)
        {   if($vf['name'] == 'Collection_PDF')
            {   $clef = $kf;
            }
        }
        
        $tri_collec[$key] = $value['features'][$clef]['value'];
    }
    
    //***** 5ème TRI sur la Sous-Catégorie *****
    foreach($tabprod as $key => $value) 
    {   //recherche de la clé Type
        $clef='';
        foreach($value['features'] as $kf => $vf)
        {   if($vf['name'] == 'Sous-Categorie')
            {   $clef = $kf;
            }
        }
        
        $tri_sscat[$key] = $value['features'][$clef]['value'];
    }
    
    //Tri complet selon les 4 ordres de tri : Famille/Type/Collection_PDF/Sous-Categorie
    array_multisort($tri_famille,   SORT_ASC, 
                    $tri_lieux,     SORT_ASC, 
                    $tri_type,      SORT_ASC, 
                    $tri_collec,    SORT_ASC, 
                    $tri_sscat,     SORT_ASC, 
                    $tabprod);
                    
    return $tabprod;
}
```

This function reorders my products well but only for each page and not for all the products. if I modify the maximum number of products per page (1000 for example), it works perfectly.
it is probably necessary to make a modification in a program before but I do not know which? Maybe the ProductListingFrontController.php program but I don't know where?
Thanks.

Comment: Hello, please read trough how to ask a question correctly, the community is hare to help, however, you must include as much detail (Sharing code, highlighting important parts, showing of a return example) so the community could precisely and effortlessly answer.

Comment: OK sorry.
I tried to be more precise.